# ALWAYS run commands with low priority on unix?

Tags: unix, scheduling, priority, nice

**I am not asking how to nice and renice** a command on UNIX.

What happens is that on a particular machine into which I frequently log I am only allowed to run long-running processes with low priority (nice 19). Is there a way for all my commands on this machine to run as if I had "niced 19" them?

Inevitably I forget to prefix the command with "nice 19" when I start it, then need to go muck around in ps/top to locate the pid of my resource-hogging process and then renice it. Too much trouble, and I risk annoying the sysadmin; is there a way to do this by default?

many thanks!
~l

Comment: It sounds like this is a sysadmin type question, about using an operating system rather than programming. It may be better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Bash, if your system supports this feature, place this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
ulimit -e 19
```

You can try it from a command line first as a test.

Answer (score 2):

You might ask your sysadmin to look into adjusting limits.conf, a configuration file that is part of PAM and is located (on my Ubuntu system) in /etc/security.

A line like

```
@users hard priority 19
```

sets the default 'niceness' for processes started by user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes your shell is `bash`.

Rather than mucking about in `ps` or `top`, just suspend the process(es) with Ctrl-z if they weren't launched that way (via `&`), and then run `jobs -l` to get a pid, `renice` that pid, and then continue the job's execution via `bg` (for BackGround) or `fg` (ForeGround).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [verynice](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/verynice/blob/master/verynice.html)? It's a bit old but still seems to be a program that might be excellent for your needs.

**Update 2019-02-06:** link updated.

Comment: Linky no worky no more.  What was verynice?

Comment: Oh wow, 2010 called, it wanted its answer back. Link updated. :)